Is this individual a second author?
I have a dilemma. I was asked to work with another individual, who was to be the second author, to update a book chapter that I authored in two previous editions of a textbook. The two of us unsuccessfully tried to meet multiple times to develop a plan to divide up the work.
The other individual submitted a list of some updated references (10 in all). I also complied my own list of updated literature. I read and reviewed all of the literature they submitted, as well as all of the updated literature I complied. The references were integrated into the chapter, but none were suitable to integrate into an "evidence table" which is a core element of the chapter. The other individual did no other work, including none of the writing for the chapter. The individual didn't review or make any final edits prior to submitting the work to the editor of the text.
Do I still list this individual as the second author? I have worked on a few other publications with other authors, but the work was more evenly divided. In these cases, each author made significant contributions to the work. The editor is aware of the situation, but said it's up to me whether to list the other individual as the second author. I don't want to slight the other individual, but their contributions were limited.

Is there a reason you don’t view this partner as a contributor you’d typically simply acknowledge? Is there career value, for either of you, to include him or her, as a second author?

Did they not make it into the evidence table because they put in little effort, or was it 100% genuine effort and the papers were just not suitable?

I suggest that you keep them as second author even if you think it is marginal. It will prevent bad feelings and open the possibility of a more productive joint effort in the future. It doesn't really cost you anything if you think long term.
I don't know, of course, why their contribution was minimal and it could be just inexperience or something more serious.
This also happens to be a good day for gift giving (25 December), though I don't really think of this as gift authorship. They made some effort to contribute at least.
FWIW, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_economy, though I wouldn't extend those ideas to gift authorship which is a sort of fraud.
